# Configuration for Redis on Azure Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, redis

We have an app running on Azure Kubernetes Service made up of several .NET Core containers connecting to a SQL database on Azure SQL. We are going to use Redis to cache some fragments and reduce number of requests to the SQL database.

At most we'll be caching 2GB in Redis. I don't care about data persistence for more than a few minutes.

In this use case below is it more appropriate to use an Azure Redis Cache instance or Redis containers in kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on yourself. I will show you something in my own opinion.

The Redis container in kubernetes, I think, will more quickly to access because they are in the same cluster. Also, it's a container, it has the least dependencies and Component, and start more quickly. If you just want to store the data in it without other requirements, it's a better choice.

The Azure Redis Cache instance, it has more function and control, and it's more secure. If you have more need than storing data, it's a better choice.

In the end, the above is just my own opinion, how to choose all dependents on your self. If you have any more questions, please let me know. Or if you think it's helpful you can accept it.